# How to statistically compare columns with values ​0 and 1? See the example

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

The table below shows the example. I have different blood donors who donated in different years. I wanted to know if there is a statistical difference between the number of donors in one year compared to the other year. The number 1 indicates that there was a donation while the number zero indicates that there was no donation.

It is worth mentioning that donors are different between years.

If anything is possible beyond a descriptive analysis, please leave your suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could summarize your data, perhaps giving the counts and percentages of donors in the two years. However, sample sizes are much too small to say that the proportion of donors has decreased significantly from 80% in 2019 to 75% in 2020.

Random fluctuations of the size you see in your data would not
be surprising from year to year, even if the true proportion of
willing donors is unchanged,

Roughly speaking, you would need about 1000 randomly chosen subjects in each of the two years in order to have a reasonably good chance (say 75%) of detecting as statistically significant, a real difference between proportions .8 and .75.